# How should I PHPDoc a callback?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a method which extracts a modified preorder tree transversal tree from the database, and filters that using a callback function. For example:

```
/**
 * Recursive function for building the Cas_Template_TreeNode.
 *
 * @static
 * @param array $rows
 * @param callback $filter A function to filter the tree by (return a value convertible to false to remove the item from the tree)
 * @return array
 */
private static function MakeTreeGivenDbRows($rows, $filter = null)
{
    if ($filter === null)
    {
        $filter = function($unused)
        {
            return true;
        };
    }
    $result = array();
    $childrenCount = 0;
    for ($idx = 0; $idx < count($rows); $idx += $childrenCount + 1)
    {
        $current = $rows[$idx];
        $childrenCount = self::ChildrenCountFromRow($current);
        if (!$filter($current))
        {
            continue;
        }
        $childrenStartAt = $idx + 1;
        $childRows = array_slice($rows, $childrenStartAt, $childrenCount);
        $children = self::MakeTreeGivenDbRows($childRows, $filter);
        $result[] = new Cas_Template_TreeNode(self::MakeNodeGivenDbRow($current), $children);
    }
    if (empty($result))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I'm not sure what the PHPDoc should be for the variable `$filter` -- it's a callback, which is what I've indicated, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Also, any other comments on the quality (or lack thereof) in this code would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The correct type-hint is `callable`, which has been available in e.g PhpStorm for a long time, and is part of [PSR-5](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) which is currently under specification.

(I'm surprised nobody else mentioned `callable`, it's nothing new and has been used everywhere for years - to my knowledge, `callback` is not and never was a defined PHP [pseudo-type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php))

Note that `callable` includes not just closures, but also "old school" PHP callbacks, e.g. `array($object, 'methodName')` or `array('ClassName', 'methodName')` and even `'function_name'`- to maximize the usefulness of your API, you should cover all of those use-cases, which is quite easy, since both [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/call_user_func) and [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/call_user_func) support all four varieties of callables: function-name as string, object/method-name, class/method-name and closure.

Comment: When all these answers were written, `callback` was the correct answer. To quote the PHP pseudo-types article to which you linked: "callback pseudo-types was used in this documentation before callable type hint was introduced by PHP 5.4. It means exactly the same." All the other answers and question predate PHP 5.4, so they were right at the time.

Answer (score 6):

"callback" does work as a valid datatype in phpDocumentor... I just verified it... using PHP 5.2.4, at least.  It's feasible that "valid datatypes" depend on the PHP version you run phpDocumentor with.

Comment: This answer was correct at the time it was written. However, it is no longer the correct answer as of PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

phpDoc doesn't really specify what the accepted variable types are, just that they should be the names of valid php variable types. In this case "callback" would be correct. That is the name of the pseudo-type in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `@param` tag doesn't seem to have been updated in eons, so it doesn't say anything about closures or even callbacks made with `create_function()`.

If phpDocumentor refuses to recognize `callback` as a data type, you'll have to go with `mixed`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it recognises `callback` as a datatype or not.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I guess you'd have to run the PHP files through phpDocumentor and find out. Or if you're just doing this informally without needing to generate the doc pages, just calling it `callback` wouldn't hurt.